# Selected option (HTML dropdown list) isn't saved to the localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, local-storage, html-select

I'm trying to save the "selected" option from the `<select>` HTML tag to the localStorage, so when I refresh the page the last selected option is selected. I can see that it's saved in the console.log, but it's not working on the page load. How can I make it work?

```
<select class="multiply_ing">
    <option value="0.5">0.5x</option>
    <option value="1" selected>1x</option>
    <option value="1.5">1.5x</option>
    <option value="2">2x</option>
    <option value="2.5">2.5x</option>
    <option value="3">3x</option>
    <option value="4">4x</option>
    <option value="5">5x</option>
    <option value="6">6x</option>
    <option value="8">8x</option>
    <option value="10">10x</option>
</select>
<p class="portion" data-val="<?php echo $portion; ?>"></p> <!-- PHP Generated value, let's just say it's "1" -->

<div class="ingredient">
  <p data-val="1"></p>
  <p data-val="5"></p>
  <p data-val="6"></p>
</div>
```

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".multiply_ing").on("change", function() {

      let multiply_val =+ this.value;
      $('.ingredient p:nth-child(1)').each(function() {
        let ing =+ this.dataset.val;
        this.innerHTML = ing * multiply_val;
      });

      $('.multiply_ing option').each(function() {
        let multi_opt = $(this).val();
        let portion = parseFloat(document.querySelector(".portion").dataset.val);
        let portions = multi_opt * portion;
      });

      let portion =+ document.querySelector(".portion").dataset.val;
      document.querySelector(".portion").innerHTML = portion * multiply_val;

    }).change();
    
    jQuery($ => {
      let $select = $('.multiply_ing');

      // get on load
      $select.val(localStorage.getItem('value') || 1); // 1 = default value

      $select.on('change', e => {
        localStorage.setItem('value', e.target.value);
      });
    });
                
  });

</script>
```

Note: there is more code than in this example, but it's irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you require you can just use `val()` to both get and set the value of the select when required:

```
jQuery($ => {
  let $select = $('.multiply_ing');

  // get on load
  $select.val(localStorage.getItem('value') || 1); // 1 = default value

  $select.on('change', e => {
    localStorage.setItem('value', e.target.value);
  });
});
```

Also note that the `each()` in your example is doing nothing and can be removed. In addition, `multiply_val` is not defined anywhere.

As a general rule, if you're going to incur the performance penalty of loading jQuery in to the DOM, then you're better off making use of it everywhere. Mixing JS and jQuery just leads to confusion.

Comment: Thank you, it works (kind of). The select value is set, but p (class "portion") and things that are actually changed with the select are not. I thought that by saving the select value these things will be set automatically, but they are not.

Comment: It works fine in isolation: https://jsfiddle.net/dLtym56x/. Are you using a third party library to style or add features to standard HTML select element? Try checking the console for errors.

Comment: I'm not using bootstrap, etc. but the content of P tags (I've added some new code in the post) is generated from PHP (it's taken from the database).

Comment: One more thing, can I make it so it deletes the value after 1 hour?

Comment: Ok, but the `p` element has nothing to do with the behaviour of the select...?

Comment: 'One more thing, can I make it so it deletes the value after 1 hour?' You'd be better off using a cookie with an explicit expiration in that case, or sessionStorage which gets cleared when the user closes their browser.

Comment: All right, I will try to do that. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

To store value in localStorage you have to use key value pair like this localStorage.setItem('selectedValue',yourValue) and to get value use key to access the saved value localStorage.getItem('selectedValue')

```
$(function() {
     $('.multiply_ing').change(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('selectedValue', this.value);
    });
    if(localStorage.getItem('todoData')){
        $('.multiply_ing').val(localStorage.getItem('selectedValue'));
    }
                
  });
```

for working code you can see this [demo](https://jsbin.com/navelexiku/edit?html,js,console,output)